# how to create page loader bar for opencart by using a nprogress

Tags: opencart

can any one guide me how to create page loader bar for **opencart** by using a **nprogress**?

Expecting an answer in detail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first load the js and css file in header.tpl

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='nprogress.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='nprogress.css'/>
```

Then add this code in footer.tpl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    NProgress.start();
    setTimeout(function() { NProgress.done(); $('.fade').removeClass('out'); }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: great @Abdullah Al Shakib working great thanks for the great help.